# Invalid Variant Type Issue - Saving from ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer to Shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, arcgis-server

I'm using QGIS 2.18.10, and I have an ArcGIS server feature layer pulled up that I would like to save locally to my hard drive for editing purposes.

The remote layer with which I am working is the polygon layer available at https://mapservices.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/cultural_resources/nrhp_locations/MapServer.

When I right click on the layer in the Layers Panel in QGIS and try to save it as a shapefile, I get an error stating the following:

> Export to vector file failed.  Error: Feature write errors: Invalid
>   variant type for field Shape_Area[34]: received QByteArray with
>   type......

The Shape_Area field in the source layer is formatted as double. I'm having trouble understanding what's causing this issue.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: One additional thing I noticed - the values in the field in question are decimalized numbers that extend roughly 19 digits past the decimal point.  I'm wondering whether they are being automatically converted to scientific notation.  They show up in the error message in scientific notation. Could this be contributing to the issue?  If so, how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here due to the following error in QGIS 3.28.12 LTS and I was trying to export a layer in a particular format:

```
Invalid variant type for field geo_point_2d[35]: received QVariantMap with type
```

I was able to get past this error by scrolling through my table under the "Encoding" heading and check the Key/Value box and I was able to export my table into another format.

[Inspired by this answer from user Timeless.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/435753)