# Error exporting .geojson in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to export a .geojson file as a shapefile but I get an error stating that "Unsupported type for field style". Any solution to that?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what types does your input file have in it?

Comment: Shapefile does not support datetime field type: do you have such a field in your layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS, make sure to check the option "Use Key/Value" for the field concerned (**'style'** in your case) when exporting a GeoJSON file into an ESRI shapefile.

[image]

Otherwise, you'll get an *Error: Unsupported type for field prop1*

[image]

Comment: How can make this checkbox acvtive while using pyqgis?
I mean, probably this codeblock gives same error beacuse of same issue:

>>> layer = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()[0]
>>> QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, outfile, 'utf-8', 'GeoJSON')
(4, 'Unsupported type for field extra')

what should do in this case?

Comment: Is there a solution for this in pyQGIS?