# "DeprecationWarning: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() is deprecated" when exporting GeoJSON in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geojson, export, vector-layer, writers

I am trying to export a layer same to like this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/435753/215676

But the difference is I'd like to do it in PyQGIS with `QgsVectorFileWriter`. Is there a way to use that 'Use Key/Value' option in codes?

Here is my command which is not working:

```py
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    layer,
    outfile,
    'utf-8',
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
    'GeoJSON',
    layerOptions=['COORDINATE_PRECISION=8'],
    onlySelected=True
    )
```

And I have this warning:

> 'DeprecationWarning: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() is
> deprecated'

As I understand because of having those JSON fields, it works without JSON fields.

Comment: Link-only Answers are deleted because they lack an Answer. This appears to be a link-only Question. Please [Edit] it to contain sufficient details that it is not required to follow the link to understand the Question.

Comment: How are you exporting a layer to get the "Use Key/Value" option to show up? I dont see it when I right-click the layer and Export - Save features As.

Comment: It is possible when your layer has a JSON field, and probably your QGIS vers. should be 3.30 or more

Answer (score 3):

`'DeprecationWarning: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() is deprecated'` is a warning, not an error. If you check the [documentation for that method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) you see that using [`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3) is recommended instead.

Once you adjust your code to use that method, the "error" will disappear.