# Adding vector layer to existing GeoPackage using PyQGIS: writeAsVectorFormatV3()

Tags: geopackage, qgsvectorlayer, pyqgs

I need to save (mostly) virtual layers to an existing geopackage. Since I was required to use the `layerOptions` parameter for primary key handling I changed my code to use `writeAsVectorFormatV3()`. [As seen here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460566/deprecationwarning-qgsvectorfilewriter-writeasvectorformat-is-deprecated-wh)

Creating a GeoPackage with `new_layer = makePermanent(layer, layer.name(), layerOptions, folder=False)` works fine but adding further layers won't work.

I wonder whether the GeoPackage has to be closed in between writing processes. Here's my code, maybe I have overlooked something...

```py
def makePermanent(layer, filename, layerOptions, folder=False):
    transformContext = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()  # required for V3
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.layerName = layer.name()
    options.layerOptions = layerOptions
    # If 'folder' is True, 'filename' is considered a full path including the .gpkg extension.
    if folder:
        if not filename.lower().endswith('.gpkg'):
            filename += '.gpkg'
    else:
        # If 'folder' is False, 'filename' is treated as just the name, and saved in the project's directory
        filename = f'{QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")}/{filename}.gpkg'

    # Write the layer to the GeoPackage
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
        layer,
        filename,
        transformContext,
        options)
    error_code, error_message, new_file_path, new_layer_name = writer

    if error_code == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print(f'{new_layer_name} saved successfully')
        new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(new_file_path, new_layer_name, "ogr")
        if new_layer.isValid():
            return new_layer
        else:
            print("Failed to create the layer from the saved GeoPackage.")
            return None
    elif error_code == 2:
        # Verify exists
        existing_layer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, layer.name(), "ogr")
        if existing_layer.isValid():
            return existing_layer
        else:
            print(f"Layer {layer.name()} already exists in the GeoPackage, but could not be loaded.")
            return None
```

Comment: I found an entry about this here, I don't want to read the whole thing, but maybe it helps you? https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2023-April/065750.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but without further investigation I came to the conclusion that the issue I am encountering is QGIS' shabby treatment of virtual layers